# Desktop shows in frame on screen

Tags: display, desktop, show-desktop

How to make this screen normal. Please check this image and help.

[image: Desktop]

Comment: can you explain your problem a little bit better?, did you install some software like nautilus or nemo?

Comment: Is Nautilus installed?

Comment: No. It was due to tweak tool. Problem resolved. Thanks guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be caused by installing Nemo file manager. If you have Nemo installed and don't want it, remove it using the Software Center or by running `sudo apt-get remove nemo`

Answer (score 1):

This problem was caused by the "Enable Desktop Icons" feature in the Tweak tool. Disabling that feature restores the desktop to how it should be.

Comment: I have the updated tweaks installed and I don't have any problems

Comment: enable desktop icons

Comment: Try asking that as another question